# mongo export array elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to export 3 different csv files, here is my document

```
{

"capacities" : [ 
    {
        "size" : "A",
        "incoming_parcels" : 27,
        "outgoing_parcels" : 0,
        "empty_compartments" : 0
    }, 
    {
        "size" : "B",
        "incoming_parcels" : 11,
        "outgoing_parcels" : 0,
        "empty_compartments" : 8
    }, 
    {
        "size" : "C",
        "incoming_parcels" : 2,
        "outgoing_parcels" : 1,
        "empty_compartments" : 7
    }
]
```

}

I would like to get all documents where capacities[1] = B and then get all fields - same for all sizes.

Here is my syntax for export :

```
mongoexport.exe --db name --collection name --type csv --out sizeB.csv -q "{'capacities.1.size': 'B'}" -f size,incoming_parcels,outgoing_parcels,empty_compartments
```

I've also tried -f capacities.1.size etc

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could take is to use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to filter your documents using the above query as your **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator and then write the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline to a specified collection using the **[`$out`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)** operator. You can then export the data from that aggregation output collection. The following outlines the concept:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "capacities.size": "B"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$capacities"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "capacities.size": "B"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {            
            "size" : "$capacities.size",
            "incoming_parcels" : "$capacities.incoming_parcels",
            "outgoing_parcels" : "$capacities.outgoing_parcels",
            "empty_compartments" : "$capacities.empty_compartments",
        }
    },
    {
        "$out": "capacities_output"
    }
])
```

Export to csv:

```
mongoexport.exe --db name --collection "capacities_output" --csv > sizeB.csv --fields size,incoming_parcels,outgoing_parcels,empty_compartments
```

Comment: thank you, gonna try it later

how can I honor you ?

Comment: @Przemek85 No worries, you could check this out [**What should I do when someone answers my question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)